# unix shell script to check for EOF

Tags: bash, shell, eof

I wish to take names of two files as command line arguments in bash shell script and then for each word (words are comma separated and the file has more than one line) in the first file I need to count its occurrence in the second file.
I wrote a shell script like this

```
 if [ $# -ne 2 ]
 then
 echo "invalid number of arguments"
 else
 i=1
 a=$1
 b=$2
 fp=*$b
 while[ fgetc ( fp ) -ne EOF   ]
 do
 d=$( cut -d',' -f$i $a )
 echo "$d"
 grep -c -o $d $b 
 i=$(( $i + 1 ))
 done
 fi
```

for example file1 has words abc,def,ghi,jkl   (in first line )
                            mno,pqr           (in second line)

and file2 has words         abc,abc,def

Now the output should be like  abc 2
                            def 1
                            ghi 0

Comment: The question & the title have little in common. This sounds like homework, which is fine, but the question needs to be a little more focused.

Comment: It would also help if you showed some sample input and the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read a file word by word separated by comma use this snippet:

```
while read -r p; do
    IFS=, && for w in $p; do
       printf "%s: " "$w"
       tr , '\n' < file2 | grep -Fc "$w"
    done
done < file1
```

Comment: still not working....could you tell me how should I check   for the end of file in a condition....I read somewhere that unix files don't have EOF

Comment: Define **still not working** and provide details how did you test it and what's not working. This if fully tested and 100% working solution. There is no need to check for EOF or `fgetc` like in your C code.

Comment: Let me give you a specific example. Say filea has  words like abc,def,ghi in first line and in second line words are jkl,mno. Now how should I extract these fields and compare it with the words in second file. I want to compare words not characters

Comment: You wrote **for each character in the first file I need to count its occurrence in the second file** and now you're saying **I want to compare words not characters** which one is correct? Better you edit the question with your actual requirement.

Comment: There is a catch here. You want to count `occurrences of "abc"`, not `number of lines having "abc"`. If the word appears twice in a single line, this code would fail...

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
words=( `tr ',' ' ' < file1`) #split the file1 into words...

for word in "${words[@]}"; do  #iterate in the words
    printf "%s : " "$word"
    awk 'END{print FNR-1}' RS="$word" file2
    # split file2 with 'word' as record separator.
    # print number of lines == number of occurrences of the word..
done
```